# Flatlist reference error when leaving the screen in a Carousel view

Tags: react-native, carousel, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist, autoscroll

I have an autoscrolling carousel in React Native and everything is working fine with images scrolling through both automatically every X seconds and manually.

The problem is when I move away from that screen that I get the following error:

[image]

Here's is my full code...

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
let flatList;

function infiniteScroll(dataList) {
  const numberOfData = dataList.length;
  let scrollValue = 0,
    scrolled = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    scrolled++;
    if (scrolled < numberOfData) scrollValue = scrollValue + width;
    else {
      scrollValue = 0;
      scrolled = 0;
    }
    this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: scrollValue });
  }, 3000);
}

const Carousel = (props) => {
  const topTenVideos = useSelector(getTopTenVideos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
  let position = Animated.divide(scrollX, width);
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState(topTenVideos);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      setDataList(topTenVideos);
      infiniteScroll(dataList);
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  const renderRow = (itemData) => {
    return (
      <CarouselItem
        id={itemData.item.id}
        img={itemData.item.poster}
        title={itemData.item.title}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <FlatList
        ref={(flatList) => {
          this.flatList = flatList;
        }}
        horizontal
        data={dataList}
        pagingEnabled
        scrollEnabled
        snapToAlignment="center"
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={Animated.event([
          { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } },
        ])}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => "key" + index}
        renderItem={renderRow}
      />
      <View style={styles.dotView}>
        {dataList.map((_, i) => {
          let opacity = position.interpolate({
            inputRange: [i - 1, i, i + 1],
            outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
            extrapolate: "clamp",
          });
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={i}
              style={{
                opacity,
                height: 8,
                width: 8,
                borderRadius: 6,
                backgroundColor: "white",
                margin: 8,
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

It's complaining about this line **this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: scrollValue });
  }, 3000);** which is inside my **infiniteScroll** function.

It looks like that when the screen loses focus, it is still searching for this.flatList.scrollToOffset.

Answer (score 1):

`You are not creating your ref properly`, You have to use `useRef` hook if you are using functional component or `createRef` in the case of class component for making refs in your component

Have a look at this.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Create your ref like below.

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null)

       <FlatList
          ref={flatListRef}
          // other props
       />

flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: scrollValue }) // access like this.
```

Comment: I get an error:   TypeError: flatListRef.scrollToOffset is not a function. (In 'flatListRef.scrollToOffset({
          animated: true,
          offset: scrollValue
        })', 'flatListRef.scrollToOffset' is undefined)

setInterval$argument_0
    Carousel.js:78:7
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0

Comment: I actually placed function infiniteScroll() within the same component and reference it the way you suggested but I'm getting the same error when I leave the screen. The carousel works as before therefore looks like you can reference it using the 2 methods however I still get `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset')

setInterval$argument_0
    Carousel.js:61:7
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
`

Comment: maybe you are passing the ref to another component for that you need to use `forwardRef`, If still error is the same make a snack on the expo with this issue, share to me, and I will fix it.

Comment: I managed to solve it. As I stated above, the problem is that infiniteScroll() kept looking for flatListRef.current even after I left the screen. I simply added a condition rendering to check if flatListRef.current exists before calling it and that's it.   `if (flatListRef.current) {
          flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
            animated: true,
            offset: scrollValue,
          });
        }` Thanks for your help anyway!